# Keeping build.bat on build machine vs on source control

Tags: git, batch-file, jenkins, build

I have a C++ project and I build it using jenkins on different slave machines. For building the project I have created a bat file, having all the configs, platforms and build paths etc. Now if I have a pool of slaves, then my build.bat should be present on all the slaves, but I just want to know what is the best way of keeping this bat file.

1) Keeping separate copies on slaves manually - In case of any changes in the bat file, I will have to update the bat files manually on all the slaves.

2) Syncing it from source control (git) - My project is on git and can be accessed by multiple clients as well, placing it there will make it accessible to the clients as well, though it will not cause any harm but still is it a good practice ?

Another option was to create a separate project having the bat files but again we will have to add an extra step to sync it whenever we are syncing the main project. So an extra overhead of maintaining a new project as well.

Answer (score 0):

Go with option 2, source controlling your build.bat. There's been many times I've had to modify a config file to include new data but forgot to apply it to all build nodes, resulting in a wasted hour.